# Why does the keyword extends of typescript have different meanings and how to understand it？

Tags: typescript

For example:

```js
type A1 = 'x'|'y' extends 'x' ? string : number // A1 is number
type A2 = string|number extends string|number|boolean ? string : number // A2 is string

interface test {
  name:string
}

interface test1{
  name:string
  age:number
}

type A3 = test1 extends test ? string : number // A3 is string, why?
```

I don't know how to understand the `extends` meaning in here, it looks like it has a different meaning.
In example A1, `extends` left is literal constant, it's `x` or `y`, of course it can't be inherited from the right--the literal constant `x`, so it's number type.
Example A2 is the same reason, so the type is `string`.
But example A3, why `test1` can extends test? I try to use Java's inheritance to understand, `test1` can cast to `test`, But how to interpret example `A1` in this way?

Can someone shed some light on this issue for me? It's been bothering me for a long time, thank you！

Comment: These aren't different meanings - in both cases it's testing whether the first type is a subtype of the second one.

Comment: TS doesn't use Java's type system, and while there are some similarities they are different enough that it's probably not helpful to think of it that way. TypeScript's type system is [structural](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and allows you to make new types via [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), neither of which are Java-like.  Let's forget conditional types (`extends`) for a minute; does [this behavior](//tsplay.dev/ND8VVN) make sense to you or do you have the same question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to explain it is to use the term `is assignable to`:

```
type A1 = 'x' | 'y' extends 'x' ? string : number;
```

`'x' | 'y'` is not assignable to `'x'`, thus the resulting type is `number`.
It is not assignable because even though the literal `'x'` is assignable to `'x'`, `'y'` is not.

```
type A2 = string | number extends string | number | boolean ? string : number;
```

`string | number` is assignable to `string | number | boolean` (all of the left hand side types are assignable to the right hand side), thus the resulting type is `string`.

```
interface test {
  name: string;
}

interface test1{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type A3 = test1 extends test ? string : number;
```

`test` is assignable to `test1` (Again, **all** properties from the left hand side are assignable to the right hand side), thus the resulting type will be `string`.

To clarify, if you wanted to break the last example you could simply add a property to `test` that is not present in `test1`:

```
interface test {
  name: string;
  city: string; // add this
}

interface test1{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type A3 = test1 extends test ? string : number // number
```

Edit:

Union types behave slightly differently because all types of the union on the left hand side must be assignable to the right hand side. We can slightly tweak `A3` to make that more clear:

```
interface test {
  name: string;
}

interface test1{
  name: string;
}

interface test2{
  age: number;
}

type A3 = test1 | test2 extends test ? string : number;
```

The resulting type in this case is `number`, because while `test1` is indeed assignable to `test`, `test2` is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still a bit confused by the instructions for A3.
Because you said `test` is assignable to `test1`, which `test` has a string property, `test1` has two properties string  and number, it's meaning `test extends test1` is `true`,  I got the opposite result in fact, it's `false`. 
So it is `test1` can be assignable to `test`, and `test1 extends test` is `true`. 
What I don't understand is why more properties can be copied to less properties if I use `interface`, it is different from when using basic properties, like `A2`.

Comment: @stringwang You're correct, `A3` works because all properties from `test` are also part of `test1`. `A1` doesn't because the literal `'y'` is not assignable to `'x'`. I'll fix the wording in the answer to make that clear.

Comment: I try to understand it in this way, `type A1 = 1 | 2 | 3`, and `type A2 = 1 | 2`, looks like `A1` is more restrictive than `A2`, on the contrary, A1 has more types but expresses a wider type, so A1 is the supertype and A2 is the subtype, and `A1 extends A2` is `false`, there is maybe value `3` can not assignable to A2.
Here the literals type are linked by the OR operator, just like `string | number extends string | number | boolean` is `true`.
This is how I understand the problem.
Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: @stringwang I think you're on the right thought... I hope I was able to provide some clarity ;)